# KineticJS: get layers minX, minY, width and height

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have an application written in the Flash & ActionScript. I want to replace the flash with the canvas and KineticJS library. I stucked with a small problem. In the ActionScript is method "getRect" (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getRect%28%29) and "getBounds" (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29) which returns the minX, minY, width and height of the object. In my case, this is layer. With this two functions I get most left and most top coordinate on the layer. Then i just set new position of the stage and all items are positioned on the most top-left side.

So, i want to create something similar in javascript. To get most left, most top visible point of on the layer. I have to check all the layers and the shapes on it, to get minX and minY.

I made the example code, which is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/JercSi/v63hC/1/

If shape is "Polygon", then all coordinates x,y are 0, also width and height are 0. I was expecting that x=100, y=100, width=100, height=100.

If shape is "Text", then i get x,y of the shape and correct width and height - which is ok, unless shape is rotated. For the "Text" object i want to get: x=-8 and y=126. and not x=150, y=150.

This is the script which should return minX and minY. It does not return minX, minY but prints coordinates into the console (use FireBug or similar plugin for your browser).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _le = stage.children.length; // get number of children (stage)
var i, j, _le2;
for (i = 0; i < _le; ++i) {
  _le2 = stage.children[i].children.length; // get number of children on each layer
  for (j = 0; j < _le2; ++j) {
    // check all shapes on the layer
    console.log(stage.children[i].children[j].getAbsolutePosition());
    console.log(stage.children[i].children[j].getX()+", "+stage.children[i].children[j].getY());
    console.log(stage.children[i].children[j].getWidth()+", "+stage.children[i].children[j].getHeight());
  }
}
</script>
```

Let me summarize my problem, i want get minX and minY and then set new position of the stage - current position:

[image: http://www.jerc.si/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/kinetic-js-stage-1.png]

new position of the stage / layer:

[image: http://www.jerc.si/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/kinetic-js-stage-2.png]

Maybe something like this already exist - without calculating minX and minY - but i didn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kinetic.Polygon does not automatically calculate min/max or width/height.**

But you can easily do those calculations and have your polygon report those values.

Here's a kinetic.polygon that is contained by a red boundingbox.

The boundingbox was defined using min/max, width/height properties that were added to the polygon.

[image]

First, this code returns min,max,width,height when given myPolygon.getPoints.

```
function getPolyBounds(points){
    var minX=100000;
    var minY=100000;
    var maxX=-100000;
    var maxY=-100000;
    for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        var pt=points[i];
        if(pt.x<minX){minX=pt.x;}
        if(pt.y<minY){minY=pt.y;}
        if(pt.x>maxX){maxX=pt.x;}
        if(pt.y>maxY){maxY=pt.y;}
    }
    return({minX:minX,minY:minY,maxX:maxX,maxY:maxY});
}
```

**You can add methods to your kinetic polygon to return minX and minY.**

```
poly.bounds=getPolyBounds(poly.getPoints());
poly.minX=function(){return(this.getX()+this.bounds.minX-this.getStrokeWidth());};
poly.minY=function(){return(this.getY()+this.bounds.minY-this.getStrokeWidth());};
```

**You can add properties to your kinetic polygon to get width and height.**

```
poly.bounds=getPolyBounds(poly.getPoints());
poly.width=poly.bounds.maxX-poly.bounds.minX+poly.getStrokeWidth()*2;
poly.height=poly.bounds.maxY-poly.bounds.minY+poly.getStrokeWidth()*2;
```

**[ Addition: finding bounds of other shapes ]**

Line: (which is really a polyline): same solution as polygon (get min/max of all points)

All rectangular shapes (rectangle, image, text, sprite): the minX/minY is always getX/getY.

Circle: minX=getX-getRadius,  minY=getY-getRadius

Curves (spline, blob) can be approximated by getting min/max of all blob.getPoints().

**[ Addition: finding bounds of rotated shapes ]**

To get the new boundary of rotated shapes, calculate where the original points have been rotated and use the usual bounds methods (above).

This code will get the newXY of any point that has been rotated around its pivot point by a specified radianAngle:

```
// calculate the distance from the pivot point to the original point
var dx = originalPoint.x - pivotpoint.x;
var dy = originalPoint.y - pivotpoint.y;
var radius = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

// calculate the unrotated radian angle
var originalAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

// the new angle is the sum of the original angle and rotation angle
var radianAngle+=originalAngle;


// calculate where the original point has been rotated to
var newX = originalPoint.x + radius * Math.cos(radianAngle);
var newY = originalPoint.y + radius * Math.sin(radianAngle);
```

**[ Addition: finding a more exact bounds of curves ]**

A more exact bounding box for curves is possible by plotting many points along the curve and finding their min/max.

This code will get the XY points that make up a curve.  In these formulae, T is an interval along the curve where T=0.00 is the beginning point of the curve and T=1.00 is the ending point of the curve.

```
// quadratic bezier: T is 0-1
function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    return( {x:x,y:y} );
}

// cubic bezier T is 0-1
function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(pct, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = pct * pct;
    var t3 = t2 * pct;
    return a + (-a * 3 + pct * (3 * a - a * pct)) * pct
    + (3 * b + pct * (-6 * b + b * 3 * pct)) * pct
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * pct) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

Here's code and a Fiddle for a polygon's bounds:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/SYp5j/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    function getPolyBounds(points){
        var minX=100000;
        var minY=100000;
        var maxX=-100000;
        var maxY=-100000;
        for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
            var pt=points[i];
            if(pt.x<minX){minX=pt.x;}
            if(pt.y<minY){minY=pt.y;}
            if(pt.x>maxX){maxX=pt.x;}
            if(pt.y>maxY){maxY=pt.y;}
        }
        return({minX:minX,minY:minY,maxX:maxX,maxY:maxY});
    }

    function newPoly(polypoints){

        var poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
            points:polypoints,
            x: 25,
            y: 25,
            fill: 'skyblue',
            stroke: 'lightgray',
            strokeWidth: 3
        });
        poly.bounds=getPolyBounds(poly.getPoints());
        poly.minX=function(){return(this.getX()+this.bounds.minX-this.getStrokeWidth());};
        poly.minY=function(){return(this.getY()+this.bounds.minY-this.getStrokeWidth());};
        poly.width=poly.bounds.maxX-poly.bounds.minX+poly.getStrokeWidth()*2;
        poly.height=poly.bounds.maxY-poly.bounds.minY+poly.getStrokeWidth()*2;
        layer.add(poly);
        layer.draw();
        return(poly);
    }


    // test
    var polypoints=[];
    polypoints.push({x:20,y:50});
    polypoints.push({x:120,y:75});
    polypoints.push({x:220,y:50});
    polypoints.push({x:120,y:200});
    polypoints.push({x:20,y:50});
    //
    var myPoly=newPoly(polypoints);
    //
    var boundary=new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:myPoly.minX(),
        y:myPoly.minY(),
        width:myPoly.width,
        height:myPoly.height,
        stroke:"red",
        strokeWidth:0.50
    });
    layer.add(boundary);
    layer.draw();


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="rotateBtn">rotate</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like your solution and it do what i want (on polygons). I am expecting to have more than 50 objects with 10+ points. That means a lot of calculations. I know it's possible to optimize your code with global/layer minX, minY. Question remains what happens with other shapes (e.g. Circle, Curves, ...) or rotated polygon (add to your shape rotation: Math.PI/4; your shape will display outside Rectangle).

Comment: I added to my answer to explain how to get the bounds of other shapes and the bounds of rotated shapes.  Good luck with converting your project!

Comment: It is working like I expected. The only disadvantage is that i have to calculate minX, minY for all the shapes. Better this, than nothing =) I hope someone will implement something like this to the KineticJS library, which will return minX,Y..for each layer, shape,..